# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute.Required is obsolete What should I use now?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, web-services

I am following this tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/authforwebservices.aspx

They have this in the tutorial

```
 [SoapHeader("Authentication", Required = true)]
```

> ```
> Warning   1   'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute.Required'
> ```
>
> is obsolete: 'This property will be
>   removed from a future version. The
>   presence of a particular header in a
>   SOAP message is no longer enforced'

So I am not sure what the "Required" actually referred to but it seems to not like it anymore. So do I just remove it. I am not sure since I don't know much about SOAP and I don't want to simple remove it and find that without it something else could go wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapheaderattribute.required.aspx) state:

> This member is obsolete and has no functionality.

Furthermore:

> In version 1.0 of the .NET Framework
>   SDK, the Required property indicates
>   whether a SOAP header must be
>   understood and processed by the
>   recipient XML Web service or XML Web
>   service client. If a recipient did not
>   process the SOAP header an exception
>   was thrown.

In other words, unless you're using .NET 1.0, it's *already* not doing anything - so you can safely remove it.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it just as I was typing - was going to say the same thing

Comment: Cool But why did they take it out? Like don't you want it too be processed? Like I am using it for authentication so would I not want it to be processed to check if its being sent and stuff?

Comment: @chobo2: I'm afraid I don't know enough about that to comment. The docs do explain how to check things if you really need to.